# Highest normal form

Tags: database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, 3nf

My exam answers key and my answer (and answers of online tools) are different for the typical "Determine highest normal form of relation" question and I want to know why.

**Exam question:** For the given relation R with schema H = {A, B, C, D, E} and functional dependencies F = {{B, C} -> {D, E}, {C, D} -> {B, E}, {D} -> {C}, {E} -> {B}}. Determine the highest normal form of R. Assume it's in the 1NF.

**My answer:**

I already have 1NF. Next I check 2NF.

To do that, I need candidate keys. "A" is not in any dependency, so it has to be in the key. I can also add "D", and from {D} -> {C} I have {A, C, D}. Then from {C, D} -> {B, E} I have all {A, B, C, D, E}, so the {A, D} is indeed a candidate key. I can do the same for {A, B, C} and {A, C, E}, so I have candidate keys: {A, D}, {A, B, C}, {A, C, E}.

2NF requires that "no non-prime attribute can be functionally dependent on any proper subset of any candidate key; a non-prime attribute is not a part of any candidate key of the relation". But I have {B, C} -> {D, E}, so E (a non-prime attribute) depends on {B, C} (a proper subset of {A, B, C}), so it's not in 2NF. Therefore it's only in 1NF.

**The exam answer:**

The relation is in the 3NF. Also [this handy tool](http://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/normalization_tools/normalization/ind.php#checkNormalForm) which checks normal form tells me it's 3NF.

**My question:**

Is this in 1NF or 3NF? My only doubt is for {B, C} -> {D, E} dependency. As I've written above, E is non-prime, but {D, E} as the whole contains 1 prime and 1 non-prime attribute. Do I make some mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming F a cover of the functional dependences of R, you are correct assuming that the candidate keys are `AD`, `ABC` and `ACE`.  So all the attributes are primes, no dependency can violate the 3NF, the relation is in 3NF, and for this reason it is also in 2NF.